# How do I (programatically) find the default style of a system control on universal windows?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I am looking for a way to find (edit) in runtime (/edit)the default style for a control (say, GridViewItem) in the resources.

I tried this:

```
App.Current.Resources[typeof(GridViewItem)]
```

But that did not work. I couldn't find any "link" from the resources to other "default" resources which may help. Any idea how to find it programmatically?

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: What's not clear about the question? I will try to clarify.

Comment: Yea, you don't want to do that man. If anything use a template selector but don't go trying to edit templates at runtime, it's not going to turn out well.

Comment: @ChrisW.: I never said I wanted to edit the template/style at runtime.  I wanted to inspect it.